# Agrupar datos en MYSQL , sin repetir fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy trabajando en mostrar unos datos.

Muestro el ejemplo de abajo para una referencia, pero es como yo, construyo los datos en el backend y necesito mostrarlos de la siguiente forma:

```
 "label": [
        "2022-11-06",
        "2022-11-05",
        "2022-11-04"
    ],
    "datasets": [
        [
            {
                "label": "api prueba",
                "data": [
                    1,
                    0,
                    1,
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "api prueba 2",
                "data": [
                    0,
                    2,
                    0,
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Es decir que cada data dentro del datasets pueda coincidir con la fecha en el label.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: Ejemplo de una query exitosa agrupando por createdDate y apiName]

Y la siguiente query:

```
Select
avg( durationProm) latencyProm,apiName , createdDate,
 qty,
 status ,
 transactionDate ,
 durationTotal ,
 createdTime,
 createdDate  
FROM
resumeMetrics r
WHERE
  r.channelID = 1151
GROUP BY 
r.createdDate ,
r.status,
apiName
ORDER BY 
r.createdDate DESC
```

Como se observa en la imagen, me repite una fecha 2 veces "2022-11-06" pero quisiera que hubiera agrupacion por fecha sin perder datos de fechas

Comment: Pero tu estas graficando 2 elementos api prueba 1 y 2, por lo que necesitas esa fecha

Comment: en ese caso para que no se repitan tendrías que hacer uso de funciones de agrupación a aquellas columnas que tienen valor distintos para la misma fecha, por ejemplo durationTotal.